# Private email addresses for private collaborators using github api

Tags: github, github-api

I want to use the github api to get a list of private email addresses for collaborators on a project.

I've tried using

curl -u username:password http://github.com/api/v2/yaml/user/show/username

but I can only access public email addresses. Is it possible to access the private email addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the version 3 of the API pass `scope=user:emai`l will give you the private email address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Github has a concept of "private email addresses".  Under each user account admin, you can list your email, but it's clearly listed as "publicly visible".  There is no private email option

Comment: You can add multiple email addresses on https://github.com/account#email_bucket . They're used to match up commits to your account. The api will let you get them for your own account but no else's.